# NativeScript Could not find module "@nativescript/schematics"

Tags: json, angular, npm, nativescript, nativescript-schematics

When I make tns generate component movies, I get terminal log:
Could not find module "@nativescript/schematics".

I tried solutions from https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/130 , but next terminal message is:

```
Error: Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
"@nativescript/angular": "~9.0.0",
"@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.0",
"reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
"rxjs": "^6.5.0",
"tns-core-modules": "~6.5.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"

"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^10.0.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
"@ngtools/webpack": "~9.1.0",
"nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.5.0",
"tns-platform-declarations": "~6.5.0",
"typescript": "~3.8.3"
```

ng --version

```
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.12
@angular-devkit/schematics   10.0.4
@angular/cli                 10.0.4
@ngtools/webpack             9.1.12
@schematics/angular          10.0.4
@schematics/update           0.1000.4
rxjs                         6.6.0
typescript                   3.8.3
webpack                      4.27.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing nativescript/schematics. I can't see it in your package.json.

```
npm i -g @nativescript/schematics
```

You have Angular/cli 10 so it schould work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see *@nativescript/schematics* in the package.json. try to have install *@nativescript/schematics*

```
npm install --save-dev @nativescript/schematic
```

See more:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/130#issuecomment-524841101